# How are race stewards selected in F1?

Tags: trivia, officiating, formula-1, auto-racing

Aside from Charlie Whiting, the FIA Race Director, the race stewards who look at and deliberate on on-track incidents are apparently not the same every weekend.

There have been races where I hear the Sky F1 commentators mention a few familiar names as part of the stewarding team, former F1 drivers like Emanuele Pirro and Nigel Mansell.

Looking around the internet, the FIA website has published biographies for known race stewards of certain race events, but they all come from different backgrounds in the motorsport industry, some of them former FIA officials and some racing drivers. (see source)

**Is there any specific criteria for selecting race stewards? Does being a former F1 driver qualify you to be one? And did these people volunteer or are they a part of a collection of people that are assigned to be race stewards every race weekend?**

> Sources (via FIA website):
>
> [Hungarian GP Stewards](http://www.fia.com/sites/default/files/external_archive/node8031/hungary-stewards.pdf)
>
> [British GP Stewards](http://www.fia.com/sites/default/files/external_archive/node4109/britain-stewards.pdf)

Comment: Are you asking about people who take decisions on racing or people (normally with orange uniform) who "help" during the races? And can you provide any souces where Pirro and Mansell were called to perform the functions you write about?

Comment: I was asking about the people who deliberate on race incidents, the ones who make decisions about penalties. People with the orange uniform are called the track-side marshalls as far as I remember.

Also, I'll try to look for those races, all I can say right now is that both instances were from this season.

Comment: The commentators on Sky F1 sometimes name the stewards (not to be confused with marshalls) and I have also heard them mention Nigel Mansell in that position.

Answer (score 5):

As described in [Formula 1, Rules & Regulations, Officials](https://www.formula1.com/en/championship/inside-f1/rules-regs/Officials.html):

- There are seven officials
- Five of the seven are nominated by FIA. These include:

  - the race director (currently Charlie Whiting)
  - a permanent starter
  - three additional stewards
  - one is an experienced former driver
- Two of the seven are nominated by the National Sporting Authority of the country hosting the race, both of which must be FIA Super License Holders

  - the clerk of the course
  - an additional steward who must be a national of the host nation

Answer (score -3):

They're nominated by the FIA. Most of them have to be FIA Super License holders and one steward must be from the nation hosting the Grand Prix.

Here's a link to the rules: https://www.formula1.com/en/championship/inside-f1/rules-regs/Officials.html

Comment: Do you have any source for this information?

Comment: Ya, the FIA website regarding officials and stewards.

Comment: Claiming a source exists and actually demonstrating the fact are two very different things.

Comment: Not sure what warranted the hostility but I will link the website below

Comment: https://www.formula1.com/en/championship/inside-f1/rules-regs/Officials.html

Comment: But your link says that only 5 of the 7 are nominated by the FIA.

Comment: Indeed. The link itself also contains information regarding how the remainder are selected.